# How to wrap Text around some view in a HStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I wanted to ask if following scenario would be possible and if yes how I could approach the problem. The following code produces the attached image:

```
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
  ZStack {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
      .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill))
    
      Text("Test")
      .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
      .foregroundColor(.secondary)
      .layoutPriority(1)
      .padding(.all, 5)
  }

  Text("This is a very long message with more words than one line can handle bla blabla blablabl")
}
```

[image]

Now in order to save more space I would like to have the next lines move to the left like so:
[image]

I have considered following approaches but none got me very far:

1. Using Swift UIs `Text()` + `Text()` instead of the `HStack`. This would not work as this method does not allow background colors (a .`background()` would converter the `Text()` to some View and therefore I can't combine it with another `Text()`). I could only change the `.foregroundColor`.
2. Maybe I could somehow write a `UIKit` wrapper for a `UILabel` with `NSAttributedString`. I don't like this method very much though, as changing background colors with `NSAttributedString` isn't a very good solution either.
3. Use a `ZStack` and maybe somehow throw a `.clipShape()` onto the longer right hand `Text()` so that it moves a little more to the right. This approach is also quite hacky since I don't quite know how to calculate the length of the first string so that I could move the second string.

Either I am missing something or this just isn't something that you could do in Swift UI or UIKit.

Comment: Let's say it right - you don't have *two texts*, you have *some view + text*

Comment: @Asperi you are right. Sorry.

Comment: Is the width of your view `Test` dynamic?

Comment: @Mofawaw Yes, it could be any text